# query for date between return empty rows

Tags: mysql, datetime, between

I have gone through lots of post and questions over web and stackoverlow.
I didnt got any solutions for below

I have a table `jobs` with fields

### jobs

```
INT |   datetime    - Format
----------------
id  |   post_date   - Fields
-----------------
1   |   2012-05-30 09:59:58
2   |   2012-05-30 09:59:57
3   |   2012-05-25 09:59:57
4   |   2012-05-24 09:59:57
5   |   2012-05-06 09:59:57
```

And below are the mysql queries what i have tried but it doesnt give any result.
It results empty records

**Query 1**

```
select * from jobs
where post_date BETWEEN CAST('2012-05-01' as DATE) and CAST('2012-05-30' as DATE)
```

**Query 2**

```
select * from jobs
where post_date BETWEEN  
STR_TO_DATE('2012-05-30 09:59:58','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') AND STR_TO_DATE('2012-05-1 09:59:58','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
```

**Query 3**

```
select * from jobs
where post_date BETWEEN  '2012-05-30 09:59:58' AND '2012-05-01 09:59:58'
```

Now, how can i get the results between the date, need help on this.

Comment: Use query 1, cast as DATETIME, not DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query 3 is the closest to what you want. Here it is with the problem fixed:

```
select * from jobs
where post_date BETWEEN '2012-05-30 09:59:58' AND '2012-06-01 09:59:58'
```

The problem is in the end of the range - you have:

```
'2012-05-01 09:59:58' -- This is the first of May
```

but you need

```
'2012-06-01 09:59:58' -- This is the first of June
```

Your query 3 returns nothing because the end of the range is **before** the start